# How to create draggable composed images in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to develop a code in Qt similar to the program "Scratch", which allows you to create a "pseudocode" just using a system of drag and drop.

For start with it, I want to create the option of drag an specific "item" or type of command, and drop it, but I don't know which could be the proper way to resize the image vertically to fit with the pieces of code of each situation, and get a system enough optimized to don't have troubles with huge amounts of pieces on it.

I'm new with the framework of Qt, and I don't want to do the whole work for nothing because is too slow. So, my question is: which could be the better way to do that system?

The system of drag and drops of Scratch creates this kind of images:

Example 1

[image: Example 1]

Example 2

[image: Example 2]

And I want to create the same structures.

Comment: You may investigate into [QGraphicsView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#details).

Comment: Btw. [Scratch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_(programming_language)) is a real programming language. Scratch code is not _"pseudocode"_ - it's code which can be executed.